# jVectorMap: How to add marker dynamically by coordinates?

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I have a map converted from an SVG file, and now I want to add marker on that map right at the cursor position. But the marker is placed at wrong position, and they don not follow any rules, so I cannot monitor and modify them correctly.
From this example: http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/ I know we can put markers on map by their coordinates, not by map longitude and latitude. But they are put when initializing the map, while I want put marker dynamically every time I click the mouse.
And from this example: http://jvectormap.com/examples/reverse-projection/, we can put marker right at cursor position, but the map requires insets and projection (to convert e.offsetX and e.offsetY to lat, long) while my map is customized from SVG file, so those information are missing.
So can you help me:
1. How to determine the insets and projection for a custom map? (I use http://svgto.jvectormap.com/ to convert my SVG file, but it just returns the paths)
2. Without using map longitude and latitude, how can I put the marker right at cursor position?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

When adding marker just provide `coords` key with desired coordinates in configuration instead of latLng:

```
map.addMarker(markerIndex, {coords: [100, 100]});
```

Comment: Thank you @bjornd, I tried it. But the marker was not placed right at cursor position. I used:  
'map.addMarker(markerIndex, {coords: [e.offSetX, e.offsetY]});'

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution that works for me

map.addMarker(markerIndex, {coords: [(e.offsetX / map.scale) - map.transX, (e.offsetY / map.scale) - map.transY]});

No matter if zooming in or not, the positioning is compensated.

Lorenzo

Answer (score -2):

I have a suggestion. If you are going to use jVectorMap plugin to treat with vector map, you can have a look on this: [AmMap](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps). I used it to solve almost problems I have when working with jVectormap. Furthermore, it also provides many awesome features with flexible configs.

Comment: does not answer the question. links to commercial website. pretty sure there is something in the stackdocs regarding this type of answer

Comment: @gerdi Oops Sorry I don't know that rule. Actually I solved that problem by combining a couple of methods to manipulate SVG to absolute coordinate and customize the jVectorMap plugin. Hard to tell you the detail since it's over one year till now. Then I found the AmMap (yes it is the commercial JS library) but I think it's just a personal share for those want more options.

Comment: No worries .. I dont think you are *not allowed to , but it seems a lot more appropriate as a comment then an actual answer, seeing as it does not answer the question directly.